# Reference request on the occasion of Maria Agnesi's birthday

Tags: reference-request

Today's Google doodle on google.co.uk, google.de, google.it, google.fr, google.ch, google.at and probably several others but **not** on google.com celebrates Maria Gaetana Agnesi, whose birthday is today.  She is the eponym of the "witch of Agnesi":

[image]

This is the curve $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$.

This has a somewhat surprising number of interesting properties, starting with things like $f\left(\dfrac 1 x\right) = 1-f(x)$ and including things like the fact that if (capital) $X$ is a random variable whose probability density function is proportional to this function then $1/X$ has  the same distribution as $X$, and if $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are probabilistically independent copies of $X$, then their average also has that same distribution.

**Has any published expository account attempted to enumerate the principal interesting properties of this curve in geometry, trigonometry, algebra, probability, combinatorics, etc.?**

Comment: I don't know. What did you find when you typed "witch of Agnesi" into Google?

Comment: Author unresponsive, question apparently abandoned.

Comment: I have not "abandoned" this question.  This is the first time I've seen comment under it.

Comment: Good. So, what did you find when you typed "witch of Agnesi" into Google?

Comment: Various things turn up, but very likely most of what one could find that's relevant here would not mention either of the words "witch" or "Agnesi".

Comment: I wonder whether ---Alexander, J McKenzie (2012) Decision theory meets the Witch of Agnesi. Journal of Philosophy, 109 (12). pp. 712-727. ISSN 0022-362X--- would be of any interest.

Comment: @MichaelHardy  Instituzioni analitiche ad uso della gioventù italiana  .. her own book. Other sources don't seem to have much info.